# How to use Spring Constructor DI in classes implementing an interface

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, dependency-injection

So I want to achieve something like this:

```
@Component
public class ComponentA {


    public void doThis(){};     

}
```

---

```
@Component
public class ComponentB {

    public void doThat(){};

}
```

---

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void doSomething();
}
```

---

```
public class MyInterfaceImplA implements MyInterface {

    private final ComponentA componentA;

    @Inject
    public MyInterfaceImplA(ComponentA componentA){
        this.componentA = componentA;
    }

    public void doSomething(){
        componentA.doThis();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyInterfaceImplB implements MyInterface {

    private final ComponentB componentB;

    @Inject
    public MyInterfaceImplB(ComponentB componentB) {
        this.componentB = componentB;
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        componentB.doThat();
    }
}
```

What I basically want is to inject different components into different classes implementing the same interface.

My question is if there is a good way to set this architecture up in this or a similar way? Or is there a pattern to achieve this in a better way?

Comment: So you basically want to use component A in both implementations of your interface, but you also what to be able to exchange the component inside implementing class for componentB?

Comment: No, I want to inject different components into different classes implementing the same interface.

Comment: What is the rule that you inject ComponentA to ImplementationA (aside from the obvious example "A")?

Comment: What about making another interface implemented by both components and change interface that you have in the question to an abstact class that has a field of type of your new interface?

Comment: A good point @michalk. But actually these implementation are some kind of handlers, which handle one case in different situation. Unfortunately the handling itself (doThis, doThat) is totally different, so I would like to do it without another interface.

Comment: Take a look at bridge pattern.